# Call to a member function get_segment() error

Tags: php, object

I'm having this problem with this piece of PHP code:

```
class Core {
public function start()
{
require("funk/funks/libraries/uri.php");
$this->uri = new uri();
require("funk/core/loader.php");
$this->load = new loader();

if($this->uri->get_segment(1) != "" and file_exists("funk/pages/".$uri->get_segment(1).".php")){
```

Only a snippet of the code

The best way I can explain it is that it is a class calling upon another class (uri.php) and i am getting the error: Fatal error: Call to a member function get_segment() on a non-object in /home/*eeeee*/public_html/private/funkyphp/funk/core/core.php  on line 11 (the if($this->uri->get_segment(1) part)

I'm having this problem a lot and it is really bugging me.

the library code is:

```
<?php
class uri
{
    private $server_path_info = '';
    private $segment = array();
    private $segments = 0;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $segment_temp = array();
        $this->server_path_info = preg_replace("/\?/", "", $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]);
        $segment_temp = explode("/", $this->server_path_info);
        foreach ($segment_temp as $key => $seg)
        {
            if (!preg_match("/([a-zA-Z0-9\.\_\-]+)/", $seg) || empty($seg)) unset($segment_temp[$key]);
        }
        foreach ($segment_temp as $k => $value)
        {
            $this->segment[] = $value;
        }
        unset($segment_temp);
        $this->segments = count($this->segment);
    }

    public function segment_exists($id = 0)
    {
        $id = (int)$id;
        if (isset($this->segment[$id])) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    public function get_segment($id = 0)
    {
    $id--;
        $id = (int)$id;
        if ($this->segment_exists($id) === true) return $this->segment[$id];
        else return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: So what is the problem? Call of a member function ... on a non-object? Please add some more information, code is not self-explanatory.

Comment: What's the library you're using? What methods does the `uri` class expose? as Mr.B says, more information is needed...

Comment: added the library code, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your calls to `get_segment()` are inconsistent.

In one case you call `$this->uri->get_segment()`, which is correct according to your previous code. The second time you call `$uri->get_segment`, which is missing the `$this->` and so is not a valid object.

Comment: Oh shi- i was looking at the first part of the line, thanks for pointing it out!